# Ensure execution order of two Apache Filters

Tags: apache, apache2-module

I need to ensure **my custom filter** always executes before the **`mod_rewrite`**. As per [Apache Tutor](http://www.apachetutor.org/dev/request#d5), *filters do not run in a deterministic order:*

> The request processing axis is straightforward: the phases happen strictly in order. But confusion arises in the data axis. For maximum efficiency, this is pipelined, so **the content generator and filters do not run in a deterministic order**. So, for example, you cannot in general set something in an input filter and expect it to apply in the generator or output filters.

How to ensure execution sequence of two filters, or is it possible?

---

**Update:**
Someone has [indicated](http://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=3084) to `mod_info` to display detailed information about modules and their order.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to understand this is to look into the apache source code. The mod_proxy and mod_rewrite usage of the ap_hook_fixups is a perfect example of how to insert a hook before or after particular module.

Let say you want to insert a hook before mod_rewrite, you can do something like this:

```
static int my_fixup(request_rec *r)
{
    /* do something with request headers before it goes to the mod_rewrite */
    return OK;
}

static void register_hooks(apr_pool_t *p) {
    static const char * const aszSucc[] = {"mod_rewrite.c", NULL};
    ap_hook_fixups(my_fixup, NULL, aszSucc, APR_HOOK_FIRST);
}
```

Also, you can check the http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/developer/hooks.html page for other kinds of hooks, or to better understand how to control hook calling order.